# Unable to access windows network share after upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: networking, upgrade, nautilus, samba

It was working perfectly, now after upgrade I keep getting in syslog

```
Oct 23 11:56:04 acop gvfsd[6776]: Kerberos auth with 'acop@WORKGROUP' to access '192.168.1.2' not possible
```

I had to install and use Dolphin because Nautilus didn't work.
Dolphin stores smb stuff in different place.